# JVM транслятор или интерпретатор?

Tags: java, компилятор, jvm, интерпретатор, транслятор

JVM транслирует или интерпретирует байт-код в машинный код, который откомпилировал компилятор javac?

Answer (score 2):

JVM содержит внутри себя и интерпретатор, и транслятор (just-in-time translator, JIT). Сначала программа исполняется интерпретатором, и для каждого метод накапливается статистика, сколько раз он вызывался. Как только обнаружатся часто исполняемые методы, они транслируются в машинный код, а редко исполняемые продолжают интерпретироваться. Этот процесс идет постоянно, самые часто исполняемые методы подвергаются перекомпиляции с многоуровневой оптимизацией, чтобы сделать код максимально эффективным.

Поэтому при любых замерах скорости исполнения Java-программы надо сначала ее "прогреть", то есть сделать холостой прогон, и лишь потом замерять время (но в том же процессе ОС, естественно).

Answer (score 0):

JVM - виртуальная машина Java - инструмент, который транслирует байт-код в машинный код и интерпретирует его.
Так что это и транслятор, и интерпретатор.

Comment: Не согласен. Трансляцией исходного кода в объектный модуль занимается непосредственно компилятор, но никак не *JVM*. Если говорить о стандортном *JDK* от *Oracle Corporation*, то этим инструментом по умолчанию является компилятор *Java Compiler* (*Javac*).

Comment: Я имел ввиду именно JVM, которая транслирует или интерпретирует(для меня не понятно) байт-код в машинный код.

Comment: Интерпретатор и компилятор(транслятор) в корне разные вещи.

Comment: @Lexoid компилятор Java преобразует исходный код вашего приложения в байт-код. А виртуальная машина Java - транслирует байт-код в машинный код. Или вы хотите сказать, что в скомпилированном Java приложении (*.jar) находится не байт-код, а машинный код? Зачем тогда нужна JVM?

Comment: @Kostya JVM транслирует байт-код в машинный во время исполнения программы, для этого используется JIT-компиляция. В то же время, JVM построчно считывает байт-код и передает нужные инструкции оборудованию в виде машинного кода, этот процесс и есть интерпретация. Так что, повторюсь еще раз, JVM - это и транслятор, и интерпретатор в одном флаконе. Посмотрите [этот](https://vadimstroganov.com/blog/chto-takoe-kompilyator-interpretator-translyator) материал, довольно понятно расписано.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос не совсем корректен, так как любой интерпретатор, так же как и компилятор, в общем случае является транслятором.